# How can I replace all spaces between words in javascript

Tags: javascript

This should be simple bu I can't get it working.

The title pretty much explains it all. I tried:

```
var tags = "best cars ever";
var hashtags = tags.replace("/\s/g", "");
document.write(hashtags);
```

and also:

```
var tags = "best cars ever";
var hashtags = tags.replace("/ /g", "");
document.write(hashtags);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to creates a regular expression or literal. ( see bellow an example with RexExp constructor)

```js
var tags = "best cars ever";
var hashtags = tags.replace(new RegExp("\\s","g"), "");

console.log(hashtags);
```

Comment: Even if @Slonski provided a better approach to my needs this is the correct answer to this question. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `replace()` with a regular expression, don't put that expression inside a string:

```js
var tags = "best cars ever";
var hashtags = tags.replace(/\s/g, "");

console.log(hashtags);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = "best cars ever";
tags.split(" ").join("");
```